# LED output with Photodiode and Function Generator

Tags: circuit-design, oscilloscope, photodiode, impedance-matching, function-generator

Some of my student and I are designing a Physics experiment involving a high power LED, a square wave from function generator (50 ohm output impedance) and a digital oscilloscope (1 MOhm imput impedance). The output of the function generator has two BNC cables. One goes into the oscilloscope channel and then other goes into the LED. The LED is coupled with a light sensor ([ThorLabs DET36A/M](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=DET36A/M&pn=DET36A/M#4577) and the output is connected to the another channel on the oscilloscope. Both these channels are plotted on the same channel.

We gave a square tooth wave of amplitude 0.5 V with a off-set of 1.5 V (so it fluctuates between (1.5-2 V). I was expecting that the light pulse from the oscilloscope would follow the same pattern as the square wave (of course with a smaller amplitude). But instead we got the waveform in the attached picture. [image]

The confusing part is the decaying peak even when the voltage is 1.5 V. This trend is similar even if I set the minimum voltage to zero in the cycle. If I extend the duty cycle of the function generator I get the picture attached above.

I am unable to understand this pattern like a RC circuit. I understand some capacitor is involved somewhere, very possibly in the photosensor but I am not able to understand what is going on physically and how to fix this.

There is a known impedance mismatch between the oscilloscope and the function generator.

Comment: First thought: Is your second channel set to AC-coupled on your oscilloscope? The picture is too blurry to tell.

Comment: I did not change the setting. By default DC coupling is selected as far as I can remember.

Comment: Perhaps double check? Many scopes remember the setting they were on last.

Comment: So I did go into that that setting to check out ground coupling and what it does (as I am fairly novice in electronics). I remember seeing that it was set to DC and after experimenting I do remember changing it back to DC. Any other potential source?

Comment: The [manual for the detector](https://www.thorlabs.com/drawings/a0052b3c794267f4-3BDE87F9-E0D6-AB91-17E6AFA95A2A5D17/PDA20H-Manual.pdf) explicitly states that it is AC-coupled, with a -3 dB bandwidth of 0.2 Hz to 10 kHz. I can't tell what your pulse rate is from your awful photograph, but if it's slow enough, this would explain your results.

Comment: The pulse rate of the oscilloscope is 1 Hz. While at the subject, could explain, or point out a source, what does "AC coupled" means

Comment: I'm finding it hard to believe that you're a physics professor. Did you even try to Google the phrase "AC coupled"?

Comment: @DaveTweed Not every physics professor needs to be familiar with oscilloscopes, and they could be new to the job. Someone with a background in almost exclusively theory likely wouldn't know what ac coupling is.

Comment: AC-coupled detectors only respond to intensity *changes*. If you point it steadily at the sun you'll get no output. Swing it away, you'll get a negative pulse: toward the sun, a positive pulse. Your detector is mostly infra-red.

Comment: Thank you @Hearth for speaking my mind. But profession and education I am theorist. But since a few years I have started several projects in introducing Physics experiment for undergrad and grad teaching which are more modernized than what is locally available here in my city and country. Another aspect of the job is to train graduates in designing physics experiments. This project here is a part of similar training. it does not teach students electronics but teaches students of electronics on its application in experimental physics.

Comment: Small correction: I made a mistake in the model number. It's DET36A/M (https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=DET36A/M&pn=DET36A/M#4577). However I checked the manual and it says that that output is DC coupled. However the manual also suggests that the output might appear AC coupled with long rise time if the battery is weak. I think this could explain the apparent result. I will check the battery. Thanks for all the useful comments. I learned something new, thanks to all you guys!!!

Comment: Hi. Just wanted to drop an update here. 1) The battery of the sensor was indeed weak and I had it changed. 2) More importantly this behavior was caused by saturating the sensor. This was pointed out by Thor Lab tech support. Once I sorted that problem I got the signal as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Following up on the discussion in the comments, it turns out that the battery of the sensor was indeed weak. However, upon changing the battery the sensor still gave the same response. On speaking with Thor lab tech support they pointed out, among other possibilities, that the sensor might be saturating. When I fixed the problem, the signals on the oscilloscope was it was expected. See picture attached. [image]